# Can I change a matrix in MathNet Numerics Library to an array?

Tags: c#, math.net

I am working on a program which needs matrix operation. I decided to use `Math.NET Numerics` library. I have a `Matrix` and I want to change one of it's values, but I don't know how.
My question is, can we have a `Matrix` as an `array`?
Can we transform a `Matrix` into an `array`?
I examined `AsArray` method in this library but the return value was null.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

`Matrix<T>` (which is the base type for all other `MathNet` matrix-types) provides an indexer `public T this[int row, int column] { get; set; }`. So you can use it to change values of elements.

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
// ...
var matrix = DenseMatrix.Create(2, 2, 0);
Console.WriteLine(matrix);
matrix[1, 1] = 1;
Console.WriteLine(matrix);
```

Gives:

```
DenseMatrix 2x2-Double
0  0
0  0

DenseMatrix 2x2-Double
0  0
0  1
```

---

To turn `Matrix<T>` into `T[,]` use `ToArray()` instead of `AsArray()`.

`MathNet` documentation says that `AsArray()`

> Returns the internal multidimensional array of this matrix **if, and only if**, this matrix is stored by such an array internally. Otherwise returns null. Changes to the returned array and the matrix will affect each other. Use ToArray instead if you always need an independent array.

Whereas `ToArray()`

> Returns this matrix as a multidimensional array. The returned array will be independent from this matrix. A new memory block will be allocated for the array.

---

**Update:**

Looks like `AsArray()` does not work at all. With `var data = new[,] { { 1d, 1d }, { 1d, 1d } }` `new DenseMatrix(DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<double>.OfArray(data)).AsArray()` returns `null`. So does `DenseMatrix.OfArray(data).AsArray()`.

---

**Update2:**

Checked with `ILSpy`.

MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the internal multidimensional array of this matrix if, and only if, this matrix is stored by such an array internally.
/// Otherwise returns null. Changes to the returned array and the matrix will affect each other.
/// Use ToArray instead if you always need an independent array.
/// </summary>
public T[,] AsArray()
{
    return Storage.AsArray();
}
```

MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.MatrixStorage:

```
public virtual T[,] AsArray()
{
    return null;
}
```

`Matrix<T>.AsArray()` **ALWAYS** returns **`null`**.

Comment: Than you, i can handel it now